# Django UpdateView - Prevent URL tampering

Tags: django, security, django-views

I have a Contact model.
The url.py has:

```
path('contact/update/<int:id>/', views.ContactUpdate.as_view(), name='contact-update'),
```

The UpdateView looks like:

```
class ContactUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Contacts
    form_class = ContactForm
    template_name = 'contact_detail.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('test:contacts-list')
```

The pk is not included in the fields of the form.

```
class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contacts
        fields = ['name', 'company', 'addr1', 'addr2', 'city', 'state', 'zip']
```

But the pk is sent in the url. The form works in the template and contacts are stored and edited with the above view without issue.

However, if a malicious (logged in user) changes the post url to reflect a different pk, Django will happily edit the hacked record.

```
ORIGINAL GET URL: http://test.com/test/contact/update/2/
HACKED POST URL: http://test.com/test/contact/update/3/
```

Django will update the record with a pk of 3.
The session and csrf tokens are all valid, so nothing flags as an error.

Is there a way to prevent this besides using a session variable with a uuid that is sent into the form and used on return to get the original pk?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Are you looking for user permissions? You can implement permissions so only certain users can edit certain data.

Comment: The short solution is you can check and compare the current logged in user's pk through `request.user.id` with respective contact's user's id from `Contacts` if you have made any relationship, say foreign key to the `User` model in `Contacts` model.

Comment: Can you please also share `Contacts` model?

Comment: I am not concerned with another user. If a logged in user decides to be malicious or just playing around, they can start to edit other records. I was interested in protection from url tampering in general.

Comment: Contacts does not have link to user. Only name, address, city...

Answer (score 0):

Users were limited to editing only contacts in their state.So they had edit permissions to the Contacts model. I solved this issue by using a UserPassesTestMixin to test the user rights on get and post in the UpdateView.